# How to detect user http-referer from telegram

Tags: php, http-referer, telegram

I want detect users come from my telegram group (inline links) by php

But server does not return `HTTP_REFERER`

How it's possible

Comment: it's `HTTP_REFERER`, but you need to check it's set

Comment: No , not set, typo mistake here meantime i do `print_r($_SERVER)` @Dale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding `?telegram=1` to end of my URL

Then i can detect users from telegram channel

Another way to create different file name or create a subdomain!

`tg.example.com/[MY-QUERY]`

Answer (score 1):

referer is a client header you cannot be sure its set. if you want to check the user comes from a telegram app the referer will not be present its a different application and a request is created by the browsr or whatever.

referers are created by the browser for links and only for the same protocol. http -> https wouldnt work.

you can not depend on that referer headers all headers are clientside. simply use a different address for the links to your site. a parameter preset if you spred links to telegram.

Comment: but by adding `?telegram=1` to end of my link, i can simple detect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

https://telegram.me/BOT_USERNAME?start=USER_ID

```
id=message.text.replace('/start ','').split(" ",1)[0]
fv.open('./id/' + str(id) + '/referal.txt', 'a').write(str(chat_id) + "\n") 
r=fv.open('./id/' + str(id) + '/referal.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")
l=len(r)
bot.send_message(chat_id, "Your ball: " + str(l))
```